# SharePointWebControls:BooleanField - text inside checkbox

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to brand a sharepoint site, and in edit mode I got several checkboxes. In some of the checkboxes I want to display text, how?

ex:

```
<SharePointWebControls:BooleanField ID="Comments" runat="server" FieldName="Comments" />
```

Text I want to insert into the checkbox "this is a comment"

I've tried

```
<SharePointWebControls:BooleanField ID="Comments" runat="server" FieldName="Comments" />this is a comment</SharePointWebControls:BooleanField>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider creating a content type for your page layout. This content type can have a field named "Comments" and with a custom display name.